# How to transform $z$ into $\hat z$

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus

Assume that we have vector $a = \begin{bmatrix} a_1 \\ a_2 \\ \vdots \\ a_n \end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb R^n$, $b = \begin{bmatrix} b_1 \\ b_2 \\ \vdots \\ b_n \end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb R^n$, $c = \begin{bmatrix} c_1 \\ c_2 \\ \vdots \\ c_n \end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb R^n$.
Then, the vector $z = \begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \end{bmatrix}\in \mathbb R^{3n}$.

How to obtain the vector $\hat z = \begin{bmatrix} a \\ a  \\ b \\ b \\ c \\ c \end{bmatrix}\in \mathbb R^{2\times 3n}$ based on $z$?

The Kronecker product is not useful in this case, because it focuses on elements, instead of subvectors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $a,b,c$ were numbers, you could multiply the original vector $(a,b,c)^T$ by

$$\begin{pmatrix}  1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1  \end{pmatrix}$$

Can you think of how to generalize when $a,b,c, \in \mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got it!

Answer (score 2):

I believe the Kronecker product can be pretty much useful. You could take.

**Approach 1:** Take:
$$z_{1} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\0  \\ 0\end{pmatrix} \quad z_{2} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \quad z_{3}=\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\1 \end{pmatrix} $$
so that:
$$\hat{z} = z_{1}\otimes a + z_{2}\otimes b + z_{3}\otimes c$$

**Approach 2:** Take:
$$z_{1} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \quad z_{2} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \quad z_{3} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
so that:
$$z'=\begin{pmatrix}  a & b & c \\ a & b & c \end{pmatrix} = z_{1}\otimes a + z_{2}\otimes b + z_{3}\otimes c$$
and take $\hat{z}$ to be the [vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)) of $z'$.